# Convertir variables

Tags: python

Comprobar si una variable numérica es de tipo real (flotante) o no.
En caso de que sea entera o decimal, convertirla a real
y si es complejo imprimir ("No se puede transformar a real un numero complejo").

```
import decimal
variable = input("Introduce una variable numérica: ")
tipo1 = type(float)
tipo2 = type(decimal)
tipo3 = type(complex)
tipo4 = type(int)


if variable == tipo1:
    print("Esta variable es de tipo real")
elif variable != tipo1:
    print("Esta variable no es de tipo real")

elif variable == tipo4 or variable == tipo2:
    float(variable)
    print("Convertida a real: ", convertida)
else:
    variable == tipo3
    print("No se puede transformar a real un numero complejo")
```

No consigo sacar la solución, no se muy bien como se utiliza la función type( )

Comment: Francisco, type(variable), te dice el nombre de la clase a la que pertence esa variable (el tipo de variable). Si tienes print(type("Francisco")), te devolverá <class 'str'>, lo mismo pasará con print(type("1.5")), pero print(type(22)), retornará <class 'int'>

Answer (score 1):

Evalúo mendiante expresiones regulares, si es que la cadena capturada por el **input()**, corresponde a un número entero o decimal, en caso de serlo, modifico su tipo a **float**:

> valor = float(valor)

```
from re import match

def recibir_decimal(valor):
   if match("^-?\d+$", valor) is not None or match("-?\d+\.\d+", valor) is not None:
      valor = float(valor)
      return valor, "Valor real"
   else:
      return valor, "No se puede transformar a real un numero complejo."

print(recibir_decimal(input("Introduce una variable numérica: ")))
```

La respuesta de la función es una tupla que contiene tanto el valor (original en caso de no poder ser transformado) y el mensaje.

Comment: ¿Estás parseando también los números reales negativos? Yo creo que sería más fácil descartar primero si es un número complejo.

Comment: Ruben García Tutor, ahora si. Gracias. Presenté la solución de este modo, debido a la forma en que se realizó la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que el problema trata sobre *la posibilidad de convertir una variable a tipo* ´float´ y por lo tanto, procedería utilizar un bloque try/except:

```
def test(variable):
    try:
        float(variable)
        return True
    except:
        print("No se puede transformar a real un numero complejo")

variable = input("Introduce una variable numérica: ")
if test(variable):
    print("Esta variable es de tipo real")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un pequeña confusión `variable` es justamente la variable que completamos con la función `input()` la cual solo retorna una cadena. Es decir `variable` siempre es un cadena o más bien un objeto del tipo `<class 'str'>` independientemente de lo que hayamos ingresado por teclado. Podremos haber tipeado `hola`, `15` o `45.56`, no importa, todas son cadenas.

Lo que si puedes hacer, es intentar convertir `variable` a alguno de los tipos numéricos y ver si efectivamente se puede. A modo de concepto el siguiente código verifica por orden de precedencia desde un número complejo hasta llegar al tipo básico que sería una cadena:

```
from decimal import Decimal

variable = input("ingrese algo:")
tipos = [complex, float, Decimal, int, str]

for tipo in tipos:
  try:
    tmp = tipo(variable)
    print("{0} puede convertirse a {1}".format(variable, tipo))
  except Exception:
    pass
```